# Showing the name of the most expensive product in vb

Tags: vb.net

i'm pretty new to programming and i got stuck trying to write a program where you type in the name and prices of products and you get back the total, the name+ prices and the most expensive product. Everything works fine except showing the name of the most expensive product.
Here's what i've done

""

```
    Public Class Mrj
    Shared Sub main()
    Dim i, n As Integer

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of products")
    n = Console.ReadLine()

    Dim Products_name(n) As String
    Dim Products_price(n), HT, TTC, TVA, max As Decimal

    For i = 1 To n

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the product " & i)
        Products_name(i - 1) = Console.ReadLine()

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the price of the product " & i)
        Products_price(i - 1) = Console.ReadLine()

        HT = HT + Products_price(i - 1)

    Next

    For i = 1 To n

        Console.WriteLine(Products_name(i - 1) & "   " & Products_price(i - 1))

    Next

    TVA = 0.2 * HT
    TTC = HT + TVA

    Console.WriteLine("Total to pay " & TTC)

    max = Products_price(0)

    For i = 1 To n - 1

        If max > Products_price(i) Then

        Else

            max = Products_price(i)

        End If

    Next

    Console.WriteLine("The product the most expensive is" & max & Products_name(i))

End Sub
End Class
```

""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using `i` to get the name of the most expensive product, but that index `i` is always `i = n` since you don't save the index of the maximum value.

You should add a new variable where you store the index everytime you get a new maximum value, and use it in the last line.

Your `for` loop should be something like this:

```
Dim max_index As Integer
    
For i = 1 To n - 1
    
If max > Products_price(i) Then
    
 Else
   max = Products_price(i)
   max_index = i
 End If
    
Next
    
Console.WriteLine("The product the most expensive is" & max & Products_name(max_index))
```

Try this out and check if it works.

Comment: Thanks! it works, but i had to add a "i = max_indx" after the For loop

Answer (score 0):

Turn on Option Strict now and forever. Project Properties -> Compile tab. Also for future projects Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults

You cannot assume that a user will actually enter a number. Test with `TryParse`.

Arrays in vb.net are declared `Products_name(upper bound)`. In this case that would be `Products_name(n-1)`

Instead of doing `i - 1` for the indexes in the `For` loop, start our with `For i = 0 to n-1`

I decided to not use the parallel arrays. Instead I made a tiny class and declared a `List(Of Product)`. I filled the list with the user input setting the `Properties` of the `Product`.

I used Linq instead of loops for sums and max. Not necessarily faster but can be accomplished in a single line of code.

I use interpolated strings to display results. When your string is preceded by a `$`, you can insert variables directly in the text surrounded by braces. The colon following `Price` indicates a formatting character. Here, I used a `C` for currency.

```
Public Class Product
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Price As Decimal
End Class

Sub main()
    Dim ProductList As New List(Of Product)
    Dim n As Integer

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of products")
    Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine, n)
    For i = 1 To n
        Dim p As New Product
        Dim pr As Decimal
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the product " & i)
        p.Name = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the price of the product " & i)
        Decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine, pr)
        p.Price = pr
        ProductList.Add(p)
    Next
    For Each p In ProductList
        Console.WriteLine($"{p.Name} {p.Price:C}")
    Next
    Dim SubTotal As Decimal = ProductList.Sum(Function(item) item.Price)
    Dim Tax As Decimal = 0.2D * SubTotal
    Dim Total = SubTotal + Tax
    Console.WriteLine($"Total to pay  {Total:C}")
    Dim Prod = ProductList.OrderByDescending(Function(p) p.Price).FirstOrDefault()
    Console.WriteLine($"The product the most expensive is {Prod.Name} at {Prod.Price:C}")
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

Comment: Mary.. Happy n.y. 